# Difference between Mullah and Ullama

Tags: terminology, definitions, islamic-scholar

Aslamu alikom Warahmatullah!

I have some doubts about the meaning of Mullah and Ullama. Is there any difference between them? Because in some countries like Iran, Afghanistan and Pakistan the word Mullah is used for Islamic scholars. Is it correct to use Mullah for Islamic scholars who studied Islamic theology?

Comment: Wikipedia: [Ulama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulama) /// [Mullah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mullah)

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to Wikipedia. But as we know that the Wikipedia is not authentic can you provide some authentic references.

Comment: Wikipedia isn't authentic, how can you make sure answers here are authentic?

Comment: Wikipedia is contributed by everyone so no one can confirm the authenticity of Wikipedia and no where in academic area the source is accepted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this seems to me a missed homework question both terms can be easily searched

Comment: I'm going to respectfully disagree with the votes to close.  1. See [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5280/351283), and 2. the Wikipedia pages give the definitions, but doesn't summarize the differences.  If it's so easy to answer, we can just answer it and move on.  Someone familiar may be able to add more insight than just comparing the two pages.

Comment: @Jamila what do you mean by it is off-topic? I think this forum is about Islam and my question is also under the same topic. If you know websites or any other link to easily differentiate the two terms please provide it here but if you don't know I will kindly ask anyone  who see your comment to give you a negative vote.

Comment: This is not a forum but a Q&A site. You have asked a question which can easily be researched we require a kind that you show at least some effort to solve your issue, you haven't done so.

Comment: @Jamila we are here to learn from each other. Find answers to our questions. If you know that link please provide it here otherwise,  your comments are meaningles. I would kindly request the admin to kick you out from here.